# Hidden Dictionary Key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that is passed to me from a function that I do not have access to the code.  In this dictionary there is a key called `'time'`.  I can `print d['time']` and it prints the value I expect.  However, when I iterate through the dictionary, this key is skipped.  Also `d.keys()` does not include it.  If it matters, the other keys are numerical.

How would I recreate this?  How do you see hidden keys without knowing the name?  Can this be undone?

`print type(d)` returns `<type 'dict'>`

Comment: Could you please paste the code snippet?

Comment: It's probably an instance of a class that acts like a dictionary?

Comment: What happens when you ```print d```?

Comment: @wwii when i `print d` i get the same set as `d.keys()`

Comment: Did you find out what type of object the function is returning?

Comment: Another way of hiding a key (when iterating or using `.keys()` or `.items()`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203728/custom-iteration-behavior-in-dict-subclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python can do pretty much anything in response to item access since any class can redefine `__getitem__` (and, for `dict` subclasses, `__missing__`). If the documentation doesn't cover it, there is no well-defined way to discover what "hidden keys" are available in any given object, short of inspecting the source code.

Comment: Unfortunately i dont have access to the underlying code, so for now I will just have to use what they gave me.  Sound like default dictionary types do not have room for hidden keys so there is no way for me to really know whats going on without access to code.

Comment: It occurs to me that if the code is written in Python (but you don't have source code, only the compiled `.pyc` file) you could probably dig around in it with the disassembler (`dis` module) to find out some stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Simple reproduction:

```
class fake_dict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item == 'time':
            return 'x' 


d = fake_dict({'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'})
assert isinstance(d, dict)
assert 'time' not in d.keys()
print d  # {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
assert d['time'] == 'x'
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: don't assume that it is dictionary, test it, bult-in function *type(d)* will tell you the class/type of the d object. Note: don't use *type* to check for type, for that use *isinstance* function.

To answer you question: Yes it can be done, see this: http://www.diveintopython3.net/special-method-names.html#acts-like-dict

Also if you are investigating dicts don't forget about *dict.items* which is similar to keys but prints out keys and values.

Lastly, don't use *print debugging*, use https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb .

this simple combo

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

will get you interactive console where you need it...

So I would say its very much possible. It's just about **getitem**... And no, its very likely irreversible.

Comment: I will do this when I get back to work on monday, thanks for the tip.  the other answer are somewhat dependent on the result of this.

Comment: I try to avoid absolutes like ```DON'T do something```.  Strategically placed print statements/functions can be very useful.

Comment: this reply was helpful.  I didnt know I could get this kind of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this could be implemented in any number of ways. Perhaps the most trivial is a `defaultdict`, although this will add keys on lookup:

```
import time
from collections import defaultdict

with_hidden_key = defaultdict(time.time, {
    "foo": 123,
    "bar": 1024,
    "bash": "YOLO",
})
```

```
list(with_hidden_key)
#>>> ['foo', 'bar', 'bash']

with_hidden_key["time"]
#>>> 1433546635.5777457

list(with_hidden_key)
#>>> ['foo', 'bar', 'time', 'bash']
```

Specifics depend on what is actually happening.