# Custom iteration behavior in dict subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class that is a subclass of standard dict:

```
class Result(dict):

    """ Dict-like object with special methods """

    def content(self):
        return self.__getitem__('_content')

    def attrs(self):
        return self.__getitem__('_attrs')
```

A sample representation in this object:

```
{
    '_attrs': {'id': 1},
    'description': 'testtest',
    'calories': 1234,
    '_content': 'Sample content',
    'name': 'qwerty',
    'price': 12390
}
```

I want my class to skip records with underscored keys while iteration.

```
# data is Result()
>>> for item in data:
>>>    print(item)

'description'
'calories'
'name'
'price'
```

How can I achieve that?

**UPDATE:**
Besides of correct answer I have also overrided keys() and items() methods to hide underscore keys even if this methods will be used in iteration:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for key in self.keys():
        yield key

def keys(self):
    return [key for key in super().keys() if key not in ['_attrs', '_content']]

def items(self):
    return [(key, value) for key, value in super().items() if key not in ['_attrs', '_content']]
```

Comment: Not related to your question but it shouldn't subclass a built-ins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just implement `__iter__`. It's important to use `.keys()`, in order to avoid infinite recursion:

```
class Result(dict):
    def __iter__(self):
        for key in self.keys():
            if not(isinstance(key, str) and key.startswith("_")):
                yield key
```

Then it will be skipped in iteration:

```
>>> r=Result({1:1,"_foo":2, "bar":3})
>>> for item in r:
...     print(item)
...
1
bar
```

Comment: Great answer. Is there a reason to use `self.keys()` instead of `super().__iter__()`?

Comment: I guess `.keys()` is more expressive and makes it clear what we want (imagine we'd subclass _this_ class...). That said, it doesn't make a difference here.

Answer (score 0):

just use `startswith` method.

```
>>> x = {'_content':3, 'data':5, '_roarr':'chen'}
>>> for i in x.keys():
...     if i.startswith('_'): pass
...     else: print(x[i])
... 
5
```